# Android ndk build: Specifying warning level for both C and C++

Tags: c++, android-ndk, gcc-warning, ndk-build

I'm compiling with ndk-build (r10e) a library mixing C and C++ files. My mk file has lines:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -Wall
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wall
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused-parameter
```

However, when I compile this code:

```
void func2()
{
    unsigned int size = 3;
    int pos;
    for ( pos = 0; pos != size; ++pos )
    {

    }
}
```

In a cpp file, I get expected warning:

```
file.cpp:4:28: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for ( int pos = 0; pos != size; ++pos )
```

In a c file, I don't get any warning...

Isn't `LOCAL_CFLAGS` the right way to specify warning level for `C` files?
Bonus question: Is there a way to specify warning level for both `C` and `C++` using a simple variables (to avoid duplicating the lines `LOCAL_CPPFLAGS`/`LOCAL_CFLAGS`)?

Comment: Have you considered that the C compiler may simply not warn for this code? Have you tried other warnings? Just a thought.

Comment: `LOCAL_CFLAGS` is applied to both C and C++ code, unless you're using an ancient version of the NDK.

Comment: For GCC at least, `-Wall` only enables `-Wsign-compare` for C++ code. For C code you need `-Wextra` (or `-Wsign-compare`). (see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html)

Comment: @JesperJuhl: Same code compiled with QTCreator using `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wall` qmake option reports the warning for the C file...

Comment: @Michael: Thanx, at leats this answers the bonus question

Comment: @Michael: `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -Wextra` works. Please post as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: Why should the C compiler warn by default for perfectly valid code? C and C++ are different languages; expecting they behave the same even for identical syntax is a **very bad idea**.

Comment: @Olaf: I bet func2 in my post behaves the same in C and C++...;-)

Comment: @jpo38: I'd be careful about that. Learn the languages! At least the signature is an obsolescence feature in C and to be removed from the standard with a future version.

Comment: @Olaf: Was just surprised by your first comment (not sure it deserved a downvote). What did you mean by "perfectly valid code"? Signed/unsigned is risky anyway, whatever languaue you are using (C or C++), isn't it?

Comment: @jpo38: Depends on your definition of "risky". It is often not a good idea, but the code is well defined. Personally, I enable a lot more warnings, including `-Wconversion` which will warn about this one (among other potentially problematic things). I also do not accept code which generates warnings, but that does not change the facts.

Comment: @Olaf: still not understanding why the conversion would have a different behaviour or different potential warning severity depending on the language...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section [3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) of the GCC documentation, `-Wall` only enables `-Wsign-compare` for C++ code. Fo C code you either need to use `-Wextra`, or enable `-Wsign-compare` explicitly.

> Bonus question: Is there a way to specify warning level for both C and C++

Yes, `LOCAL_CFLAGS` is applied to both C and C++ code. ([source](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html))